This API controller is working fine locally but when the server is deployed as lambda function the downloaded zipfile is corrupt
export const downloadFiles3 = async (req: Request, res: Response) => {
    const key = req.params.key;

    try {
        const getObjectParams = {
            Bucket: process.env.AWS_BUCKET || '',
            Key: key,
        };

        const data = await s3.getObject(getObjectParams).promise();

        res.setHeader('Content-Type', 'application/zip');
        res.setHeader('Content-Disposition', `attachment; filename=${key}`);

        res.send(data.Body);

        console.log('File sent successfully.');
    } catch (error) {
        if (!res.headersSent) {
            if (error instanceof Error) {
                console.log('Error retrieving file content:', error);
                res.status(500).json({
                    message: 'Error retrieving file content',
                    error: error.message,
                });
            } else {
                console.log('Unexpected error:', error);
                res.status(500).json({
                    message: 'Unexpected error',
                    error: String(error),
                });
            }
        } else {
            console.log('Response headers already sent:', error);
        }
    }
};

I tried to stream the response , it also worked locally but not when i deployed on aws.
I am getting no errors in aws cloudwatch.
the zipfile being downloaded is corrupt

Could you provide us more details on 1). The memory size allotted to your Lambda function 2). The chip architecture of your development machine and 3). The chip architecture assigned to the Lambda running this code?

Where is your Lambda handler code?

@AllanChua
my development machine is x64.
As for the lambda function
architecture is x86_64, memory size is 512 mb, timeout is 1 min
the zip files that i am trying to download from s3 bucket are in kbs not even mbs
